# vk.api файлы парсер

Tags: php, массивы, vkontakte-api

Есть парсер файлов с ВК.
Работал два месяца, теперь сломался (
API отдает

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["response"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["0"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["1"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (7) {
      ["did"]=>
      int(12345)
```

Мне этот did надо присвоить.
Если оставить просто $test=json_decode(file_get_contents($sRequest)); то вылетает с ошибкой Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.
Если делать $test=json_decode(file_get_contents($sRequest),true); то получаем

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1000)
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["did"]=>
      int(12345)
```

но значения не присваивает.
 Присваиваю так:

```
$did=$test->response[$e_sch]->did;
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: учить матчасть более усердно $test['response'][1]['did']

Comment: ну работало же) Почему сломалось?

Comment: в какой строке выскакивает эта ошибка?

Comment: Вот в этой $did=$test->response[$e_sch]->did;

Comment: Спасибо $test['response'][1]['did'] заработало. Но почему сломалось то?